# Getting sitecore item id from link and apply template for this item (xslt)

Tags: xslt, sitecore, sitecore6

In Sitecore I have an item of template that contains a field with a link to another item. I want to apply template to an item which id is specified in this link.
Field contains link like this:

```
<link url="/sitecore/content/.." linktype="internal" id="{AATB8C7-BBA55A..}" />
```

I have a variable (var) that gets item id from this link. When I'm just writing this id in apply template it works fine, but when I'm writing a variable in apply template it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[@template='mytempalte']">
   <xsl:variable name="var">  
     <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Field',.,'id')"/> - //(this gets an id from link)
   </xsl:variable>       
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="other" select="sc:item('$var',.)" /><br />            
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes aroudn the var in the apply-templates line:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="other" select="sc:item($var,.)" /><br />
```